# Sysnative on Vista RTM

Tags: windows, architecture, windows-vista

I am currently writing a batch script that will start processes on an operating system. This batch script is called from a test application that is built and run as a 32-bit application on both 32-bit and 64-bit operating systems. The batch script is written as follows:

```
set EXE=%1
if exist %WINDIR%\sysnative\%1 ( set EXE=%WINDIR%\sysnative\%1 )
start "" "%EXE%"
```

I am using the sysnative variable to start up 64-bit applications on 64-bit operating systems and 32-bit applications on 32-bit operating systems. I use this script on operating systems of Vista and beyond. It works properly on all operating systems except Windows Vista x64 RTM. When called, I receive a "The application has failed to start because its side-by-side configuration is incorrect."

I have opened a 32-bit command line on Windows Vista x64 RTM and navigated to C:\Windows\sysnative and attempted to call notepad.exe, calc.exe, etc. from there and always receive the same error. I've also tried uninstall and reinstalling the Microsoft Visual c++ 2008 Redistributable Packages but to no avail. This issue is only encountered on Windows Vista x64 RTM. Any thoughts?

Comment: Look in the Windows Application event log for a more detailed error message.  Ask questions about it at superuser.com

Comment: Note that Vista RTM is out of support, everybody should have had service pack 2 installed ages ago.  Does installing SP2 resolve the problem?

Comment: Can you launch the 64-bit version of cmd.exe from the 32-bit command line?  If so, that might be a workaround.